# One table for multiple databases

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to have one table for multiple databases?

E.g. I have a table 'Cards' in database1, and the "shadow" of this table in database2 and database3.

So, when I make SELECT, UPDATE or other operations from any database, I receive or change data in this table and changes seen in all databases.

Comment: I think "mysql replication" i what you are looking for

Comment: There is no way to achieve what you want. Can you elaborate your usecase a bit more, why do you want to update from different database, instead from just one.

Comment: I have multiple databases (on one server) for different firms. But one table, e.g. "clients" - must be the same for all firms. And all changes to this table must be seen from all users. May be I can create new database with this table, and do something with foreign keys in all old databases?

Comment: May be I can store this table in other file? May be multiple databases can represent csv or other file as table, and it will be one file for multiple databases?

Comment: This is why they invented schemas (kind of a namespace for tables) in PostgreSQL and alike. There you can grant per-schema access and have all sorts of interchange including foreign keys between schemas. It's really hard to get back to MySQL from that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the same by user permissions at database level.

Suppose you keep all the tables for Client A in DatabaseA and only set accesible to userA.

```
DatabaseA - read/write  userA
```

Similar case for Client B,keep all the tables in DatabaseB which is accesssible via userB.

```
DatabaseB - read/write  userB
```

Now keep a common database, from where both userA and userB has read/write permission on it.

```
CommonDatabase - read/write both userA and userB
```

Comment: I understand this solution, but may be some other way, when userB and userA did not access other databases except baseB for userB and BaseA for userA